# Download attribute html

Tags: html, download, atom-editor

I have been trying to make my code download the Stanford cheatsheet instead of taking me to the website when clicking the link, it has not been doing the requested action any help and has just carried on taking me to the site? 
I'm using chrome, atom editor and this is my first website that I am making so quite aware that it might be a little issue.

```
<a href="https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf" download>Cheatsheet</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes):

> This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.

You can't use it to force a browser to download a resource from another website.